# ibm domino server mail.box: field is too large

Tags: ibm, ibm-domino, messaging

we have a Domino server with one mail.box database. When a user tries to send a message to a local user group the server returns an error:

```
Field is too large (32k) or views column & selection formulas 
are too large: SERVERNAME mail.box.
```

The group in question contains 940 names. If I write them into a text file in canonical format it is ~24KB so not more than 32KB. The message itself contains some short text and a document link which points to a PDF file which is however more than 32KB in size.
If I split the names into two separate groups and I send the same message using these two groups as the recipients the server sends the message withou any error.

Do you have any experience on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group is too large. Split into two groups of less than 15K, and create a master group that lists the two groups.  There's a lot of confusion over the limits in Notes and Domino. The reality is that there are multiple limits, including the text field size limit and summary buffer size limit - (how much you can store, versus how much you can look up in a view.  Group resolution for addressing relies on a view lookup, so the summary buffer limit applies, and that's 15K.

Documentation on this stuff is inconsistent, and error messages are often unhelpful.  Here's a link to a doc that has collected a lot of information about different  [limits in Notes and Domino](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/DominoLimits), based on both official info and community experience.